# Testing method calls

Tags: node.js, node.js-tape

I'm a bit of a hacker (i.e. write some code and manually test the functionality) but now I want to add a bit more structure to my coding by adding some unit tests and follow a TDD approach. But I'm struggling to build a unit test that validates a method. So any insight would be appreciated.

I want to test my *readDirectories* method, but as it's asynchronous I'm going to have to use setTimeout - but my test keeps returning an error:

**test.js**

```
 test('The readDirectories method', (t) => {
  const xyz = new abc('/foo/bar/', '/foo/baz/');
  const expected = ['/foo/bar/Download', '/foo/bar/HardDrive' ];

  xyz.readDirectories(xyz.source)

  setTimeout(() => {
    let actual = xyz.directories;
    t.equal(actual, expected, 'should produce an array of subdirectories');
  }, 10);

});
```

**console**

```
operator: equal
expected: |-
  [ '/foo/bar/Download', '/foo/bar/HardDrive' ]
actual: |-
  [ '/foo/bar/Download', '/foo/bar/HardDrive' ]
at: Timeout.setTimeout (/home/user/Documents/app/tests/testModel.js:33:7)
```

Having looked at the example on [Tape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape) I believe I'm doing everything correctly...but then again I could just be doing something stupid! How do I get my test to pass???

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the test was failing due to the `.equal` test. `.equal` tests the my results are both arrays whereas `.deepEqual` tests that the two arrays have the same structure and nested values.

From the [Tape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape)
website:

**t.equal()**

> Assert that actual === expected with an optional description msg.

**t.deepEqual()**

> Assert that actual and expected have the same structure and nested
>   values using node's deepEqual() algorithm with strict comparisons
>   (===) on leaf nodes and an optional description msg.